# How to to read data from database table (AWS RDS Mysql) in different AWS regions and based on the result update the db in one of the regions?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Have these sample tables across 3 different regions in AWS

```
1. DB1.items (us-east-1)
2. DB2.items (ap-south-1)
3. DB3.items (eu-central-1)
```

There is another table `MainDB.globaltracker` (us-east-1).
I am trying to get count of items in 1,2,3 in the above table.
What is the best way to do this from us-east-1 itself?

The mundane way would be manually and individually get data from each region and update in the desired region, are there better ways to do this in some automated way. For example if i have a script to do this operation periodically, how can i go about it?
Are there efficient ways to handle the cross region reading from one region?

Comment: Not clear what is the issue. You do it the same way as if MySQL was on three different hosts. Just use different hostname for each database.

Comment: @Marcin revised with some more data